# How to make attribute set in model method available in controller? attr_accessor not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, attr-accessor

My sessions controller method (for an API) uses a model method to generate a token. Next it should send the token to the front end using json. However, at the `render json` line, the `api_token` isn't available anymore and is `nil`. How should one handle this?

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ApiSessionsController < Api::BaseController
      def create
        user = User.friendly.find_by(email: create_params[:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(create_params[:password])
          user.create_api_token
          render json: { api_token: api_token }, status: :ok
        else
          render json: {errors: "wrong credentials" },  status: :unauthorized
        end
      end
   end 
  end 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :api_token
    has_secure_password

    def create_api_token
      begin
        self.api_token = User.new_token
        api_digest = User.digest(api_token)
      end while self.class.exists?(api_digest: api_digest)
      update_attributes(api_digest: api_digest, api_sent_at: Time.zone.now)
    end

    def User.digest(string)
      cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
      BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the line should look like

```
render json: { api_token: user.api_token }, status: :ok
```

Your controller code references to `api_token` variable which is not defined and hence you receive `nil`

Comment: Maybe I'm doing this wrong but I'm saving only an encrypted digest of the token to the database. So `user.api_token` does not exist (`user.api_digest` does exist). For authorization the token is compared with the digest. I'll add the digest method to the OP.

Comment: @Marty what is your question?

Comment: Basically how to solve this. I require the value for `api_token` in the controller. I understand that in the current set up it's value is unavailable in the controller. The only alternative set up I can come up with is to place the full code of `create_api_token` in the controller. But that seems not right/efficient. Would you agree this is the only/best solution, or do you see a better one?

Comment: @Marty idk, you already can get access to `api_token` in your controller. For me it seems fine to use current code.

Comment: @Marty it should be available. Check that `User.new_token` actually returns not `nil`

Comment: Inside the model method `User.new_token` indeed is not `nil`. But once you go from the model method to the controller method, the controller method has no knowledge of the value that was given to `api_token` inside the model method. And since `api_token` is not written to the database (which is the correct behavior; we only write the digest to the database), it can also not be called on using `user.api_token`.

Comment: @Marty then post your entire model and controller as well as details on your environment. `attr_accessor` works perfectly fine for me http://pastebin.com/FsRdTmMg

Comment: Thanks, added it to the OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101358/discussion-between-alik-and-marty).

Comment: Yes, typo removed, and now it works (after changing `api_token` to `user.api_token` as suggested.